# Matlab cell2mat error: all contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to apply the cell2mat function to a cell consisting of strings that are either empty or are integers. I get this error telling me that the contents of the cell are not all of the same data type, even though when I ran "iscellstr" on an index with an empty string and an index with an integer sting, both returned 1, for true. What else could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [str2double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) instead of cell2mat.

You probably have empty cells `[]` instead of empty strings `''`.

Example:

```
>> M = {'123'; ''; []; '-2'}

M = 

    '123'
    ''
    []
    '-2'
```

Notice there are empty cells and empty strings. `cell2mat` raises this error:

```
>> cell2mat(M)
Error using cell2mat (line 46)
All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.
```

But `str2double` returns this:

```
>> str2double(M)

ans =

   123
   NaN
   NaN
    -2
```

Comment: Yeah, i think that's my problem. Is there a quick way to turn all the empty cells into empty strings?

Comment: Sure, just do this: `M(cellfun(@isempty,M)) = {''}`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!